# Torque transmission in a gear system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, torque

A gear system is composed by:

- a central gear (thin disc) of radius $R_1$ and mass $m_1$ whose rotation axis pass through his center O;
- two satellite gears (thin discs) of radii $R_2$ and masses $m_2$. These two gears are placed so that they stay in an opposite position around the central one, and are maintained in contact with it thanks to an inextensible bar (whose mass is negligible) which is fixed at point O so that it cannot rotate.

The system is placed horizontally and initially it is at rest. At a certain time an external variable moment of a force is applied to the central gear. Below there is a scheme of what is happening:

[image]

**So I want to find the angular acceleration of the gears.**

***Attempt to a solution:***

Tangential acceleration of disc 1 is equal to tangential acceleration of discs 2.

$$a{_T}_1=a{_T}_2,\space\space\space\space\space R_1\alpha_1=-R_2\alpha_2,\space\space\space\space\space \alpha_2=-\frac{R_1}{R_2}\alpha_1$$

Then I imposed:

$$\tau=I_1\alpha_1-2I_2\alpha_2 = I_1\alpha_1-2I_2\left(-\frac{R_1}{R_2}\alpha_1\right)= \frac{\alpha_1}{R_2}\left(R_2I_1 + R_1I_2\right)$$
where $I_1=\frac{1}{2}m_1R_1^2$ and $I_2=\frac{1}{2}m_2R_2^2$. However, as noted by FGSUZ, this is wrong since torques $I_1\alpha_1$ and $I_2\alpha_2$ are referred to different points. So the question is: *how will the motor torque $\tau$ from gear 1 be transmitted to the other gears?*

Comment: Why are you computting a "total torque"?  (summing torques) They are referred to different points. You should use that $\tau_i=I_i \alpha_i$, for each one.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's right, but I supposed that the sum of all torques should be equal to the external torque ($\tau$). Maybe I should also use Huygens-Steiner theorem for the moments of inertia?

Comment: You can only sum otrques if they all are referred to the same point, you know. Anyways, wouldn't it be easier to use that, since $R_1 \alpha_1 = R_2 \alpha_2$, then $R_1 \tau_1/I_1 = R_2 \tau_2 /I_2 $?

Comment: Then I would obtain just one equation with two unknowns, if I understood correctly... since $R_1\alpha_1=-R_2\alpha_2$ and $R_1\tau_1/I_1=-R_2\tau_2/I_2$ are equivalent

Comment: But isn't $\tau_1$ the same you are externally appliying?

Comment: I don't think so. When you apply the external torque in this case, I think that one should also consider the contribuition of the other discs which tend to decrease the angular acceleration of the central disc, because of the static friction between the discs. Also the angular acceleration of disc 1 cannot be the same with or without the satellite discs.